# How can I copy artifacts from executed jobs with declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My pipeline script looks like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'my-pc'
    }

    stages {
        stage ('Build') {
            steps {
                build job: 'myjob', parameters: [string(name: 'BRANCH', value: 'master')]
            }
            post {
                always {
                    sh 'echo TODO: copy artifacts here'
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I want to copy artifacts generated by *myjob*. How can I do this?

Jenkins documentation page ["Recording tests and artifacts"](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/tests-and-artifacts/) has an instruction which is not applicable for my pipeline (in my case artifact is generated by a separate job).

Comment: can the other job handle the responsibility of archiving the artifacts? and then you can grab them from the top-level job?

Comment: @KevinBurnett *myjob* produces artifact and puts it into different PC. How can I pass artifact location from *myjob* to pipeline? What is the recommended way to copy the artifact from that location into pipeline workspace directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Copy Artifact plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) and then you can use it with `step` step, which allows to call builders or post-build actions as in Freestyle jobs. See Pipeline Syntax of your job and consult Snippet Generator. (https://[jenkins-url]/[path-to-your-job]/pipeline-syntax/)

This is how to copy all artifacts from job `myjob` to current pipeline job workspace:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'my-pc'
    }

    stages {
        stage ('Build') {
            steps {
                build job: 'myjob', parameters: [string(name: 'BRANCH', value: 'master')]
            }
            post {
                always {
                    step([
                        $class: 'CopyArtifact',
                        filter: '*',
                        projectName: 'myjob',
                        selector: [
                            $class: 'StatusBuildSelector',
                            stable: false
                        ]])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Snippet Genearator URL does not work on my Jenkins 1.0.1  · Core 2.46.1  · 9b77619 -- I get 404 error here. Regarding "CopyArtifact" step -- I will try that one but it looks a little bit *hackish*. Is it the only one officially supported way to do this?

Comment: Oh I found out the `CopyArtifact` comes with [Copy Artifact plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) which we had installed. Here is [CloudBees blog post](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/copying-artifacts-between-builds-jenkins-workflow) about it. Editing my answer.

Comment: Does this work if `myjob` is also built by other pipelines? It will retrieve the exact job built by the current pipeline?

Answer (score 3):

There is a simpler syntax than what Travenin and Vadim Kotov wrote above. It was introduced in version 1.39 of the plugin. You can use the following to copy all artifacts from the last successful run of `myJob`:

```
pipeline {
    // pipeline code

    steps {
        copyArtifacts(filter:'*', projectName: 'myJob', selector: lastSuccessful())
    }

    // pipeline code
}
```

This syntax works with both scripted and declarative pipeline. Check out the available parameters for the copyArtifacts function on the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact#CopyArtifactPlugin-Pipelinesyntax) wiki page.